# how to next detailView like in Mail-App

Tags: ios, uitableview, detailview

i want to jump in my detailview through the rows of my tableview.

passing the data from the tableview to detailview works fine.
passing the indexpath.row working fine, too.

in the detailview i can change the indexpath of the row and by returning to the tableview the changed row is selected right.

And my problem is that i cant view the data of new selected row in the detailview.

i hope you understand what i am trying to do :)

for example like in the mail app: i want to push the "next" button and get the associated data .

Next function:

```
- (IBAction)nextRow:(id) sender {
NSLog(@"nextBtn");


TableRotateViewController *parent = (TableRotateViewController *)self.parentViewController;

NSIndexPath *actualIndexPath = detailselectedRow;
NSIndexPath * newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:actualIndexPath.row+1 inSection:actualIndexPath.section];


if([parent.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]) {
    UIView * subview = (UIView *) [parent.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    UITableView *tView = (UITableView *) subview;


    [tView selectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
    [tView.delegate tableView:tView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath];
}
}
```

Here is my sample application for better understanding what i have done jet: http://www.file-upload.net/download-3896312/TableRotate.zip.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like to show new detail information when click left or right button in detail Page , right?

In the Parent View Class (TableView Layout), you should create NSMutableArray that contain some specific object (ex. "MailDetailObject" that containg data1 , data2 ,data 3 ,... as you wish)

and you could keep each MailDetailObject contain each detail information and put them together to NSMutableArray in Parent View Class

and now , when you `didselectRowAtIndexPath` in tableView , send this NSMutableArray and your current index on tableView to DetailView (Don't forget to create this property in DetailView for refer object that send from parentView)

In the detailView , `(IBAction)nextRow Method` , if you click next you can refer to the next index and lookup in NSMutableArray that have sent from your parentView and get the next index information to display

hope it helps you

Comment: i am trying to do like you said. but how can i save object data in mutablearrey? [mutableArray setValue:data_X forKey:@"MailDetailObject"] doesnt save anything to the mutableArray.

Comment: use [mutableArray addObject:yourObject];
if you wanna know how length of your mutableArray just [mutableArray count];

Comment: i am already using [mutableArray addObject:] in my app. Sorry i was confused cause of "MailDetailObject", thought about saving in specific key values. I have do it like you said and my problem is solved...for the first time :) thank you very much, have fun with the bounties

Comment: can you tell me how to solve it, when i am using coreData? or should i start a new question?

Comment: glad to help you . be simple , try to use simple method or tool that don't let your code complexly

Comment: see above comment: can you tell me how to solve it, when i am using coreData? or should i start a new question?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. I'm not sure about using coreData so much. In my opinion, try to store your mutableArray that contain all of your detail data with some unique key to store data (NSUserdefault?) in parentView. and read it again and deal with them in detailView. hope it can help you